# How can I join two queries which tables have similar names?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, google_ads and facebook_ads, and their schema are very similar; the only difference is that google_ads has more columns.

I need to join those tables and their columns with similar names and return a single table with both data.

The content of the tables are:

google_ads table:

```
id | campaign | platform |
01 | new app  | google   | 
02 | old app  | google   |
```

facebook_ads table

```
id | campaign  | platform  | 
01 | food app  | facebook  | 
02 | music app | instagram |
```

After joining them I need something that look like this:

new table

```
campaign  | platform  |
new app   | google    |
old app   | google    |
food app  | facebook  |
music app | instagram |
```

I thought the code below was able to do that, but I was wrong,

```
SELECT
  date,
  campaign,
  platform
FROM
  `facebook_ads` AS fb
  JOIN   `google_ads` AS ads
  ON  fb.date = ads.date
WHERE
  fb.campaign like "%app%" AND ads.campaign like "%app%"
```

When i run this query i get an error saying that the campaign and platform names are ambiguous. I could solve this by writing fb.campaign, fb.platform, ads.campaign and ads.platform, but i don't want that.

Can you guys help me out with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Your query is not consistent with your sample data, so it is unclear what you are doing.

Comment: Your sample data needs UNION, not JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data, you want `union all`:

```
select id, campaign, platform
from google_ads
union all
select id, campaign, platform
from facebook_ads;
```

Your query references other columns and does not show a clear relationship with the sample data.